# Arguments to ExactTarget SOAP Query

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, query

Can I pass an argument, for example SendId to a ExactTarget query?
I am trying to understand the capabilities and uses for the ExactTarget Queries.
I learned that they have to be created on the ExT site, but I do not see a field there to specify any external arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to know about queries lives [on this page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

This section suggest that variables are not allowed:

- Unsupported elements

  - ***Variables***
  - Cursors
  - User Defined Functions
  - Transaction and Locking
  - GOTO
  - PRINT
  - Any sp_* stored procedure
  - EXEC
  - Temporary Tables and Common Table Expressions
  - TEXT and IMAGE Functions